# How should the gradle build scripts be to modularize this application?

Tags: gradle, refactoring, javafx-8, multi-project, griffon

I am trying to apply an example from the book *Gradle in Action* to learn how to separate a gradle application into subprojects. I did the example in the book and everything worked out fine.

I decided to apply the same concepts to a sample application from the Griffon Framework called [minimalistic build](http://griffon-framework.org/tutorials/6_minimalistic_build.html), source code: [sources](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7707848/simplified.zip). I selected this application because it follows the normal application structure instead of Griffon's, and I was trying to fill the gap (IMHO) in Griffon's documentation for multi project builds: it has one exaple that uses Open-Dolphin, Swing, JavaFX, Servlets that I felt it was too complicated to learn the basics.

Of course I hit the wall big time, multiple times...

Griffon's JavaFX application has the following structure:

```
├── build.gradle
├── config
│   └── HEADER
├── gradle
│   ├── functional-test.gradle
│   ├── integration-test.gradle
│   ├── javafx-plugin.gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── src
    ├── functional-test
    │   └── java
    │       └── org
    │           └── example
    │               └── SampleFunctionalTest.java
    ├── integration-test
    │   └── java
    │       └── org
    │           └── example
    │               └── SampleIntegrationTest.java
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   ├── Config.java
    │   │   └── org
    │   │       └── example
    │   │           ├── Launcher.java
    │   │           ├── SampleController.java
    │   │           ├── SampleModel.java
    │   │           ├── SampleService.java
    │   │           └── SampleView.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       ├── griffon-icon-128x128.png
    │       ├── griffon-icon-16x16.png
    │       ├── griffon-icon-24x24.png
    │       ├── griffon-icon-256x256.png
    │       ├── griffon-icon-32x32.png
    │       ├── griffon-icon-48x48.png
    │       ├── griffon-icon-64x64.png
    │       ├── griffon.png
    │       ├── log4j.properties
    │       ├── messages.properties
    │       ├── META-INF
    │       │   └── griffon
    │       │       ├── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonController
    │       │       ├── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonModel
    │       │       ├── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonService
    │       │       └── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonView
    │       ├── org
    │       │   └── example
    │       │       └── sample.fxml
    │       └── resources.properties
    └── test
        └── java
            └── org
                └── example
                    ├── SampleControllerTest.java
                    └── SampleServiceTest.java
```

The **build.gradle** file content is:

```
// tag::plugins[]
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version '0.12.0'
    id 'com.github.hierynomus.license' version '0.11.0'
}

apply from: 'gradle/javafx-plugin.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/integration-test.gradle'
apply from: 'gradle/functional-test.gradle'
// end::plugins[]

// tag::javafx[]
javafx {
    mainClass = 'org.example.Launcher'
}
// end::javafx[]

// tag::dependencies[]

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.griffon:griffon-javafx:${griffonVersion}"
    compile "org.codehaus.griffon:griffon-guice:${griffonVersion}"

    runtime('log4j:log4j:1.2.17') {
        exclude group: 'ant',         module: 'ant-nodeps'
        exclude group: 'ant',         module: 'ant-junit'
        exclude group: 'ant-contrib', module: 'ant-contrib'
    }
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21'

    testCompile "org.codehaus.griffon:griffon-javafx-test:${griffonVersion}"
    testCompile 'pl.pragmatists:JUnitParams:1.0.5'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.59-beta'
}
// end::dependencies[]

// tag::resources[]
processResources {
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude '**/*.properties'
        exclude '**/*.xml'
    }
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include '**/*.properties'
        include '**/*.xml'
        filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            'application.name'   : project.name,
            'application.version': project.version,
            'griffon.version'    : griffonVersion
            ])
    }
}
// end::resources[]

license {
    header = rootProject.file('config/HEADER')
    strictCheck = true
    ignoreFailures = true
    mapping {
        java = 'SLASHSTAR_STYLE'
        fxml = 'XML_STYLE'
    }
    ext.year = '2016'
    exclude '**/*.png'
}
```

And the structure I was trying to achieve is:

```
├── build.gradle
├── config
│   └── HEADER
├── gradle
│   ├── functional-test.gradle
│   ├── integration-test.gradle
│   ├── javafx-plugin.gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── launcher
│   ├── launcher-build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── Config.java
│               └── org
│                   └── example
│                       └── Launcher.java
├── resources
│   ├── resources-build.gradle
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               ├── application.properties
│               ├── griffon-icon-128x128.png
│               ├── griffon-icon-16x16.png
│               ├── griffon-icon-24x24.png
│               ├── griffon-icon-256x256.png
│               ├── griffon-icon-32x32.png
│               ├── griffon-icon-48x48.png
│               ├── griffon-icon-64x64.png
│               ├── griffon.png
│               ├── log4j.properties
│               ├── messages.properties
│               └── resources.properties
├── service
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── META-INF
│   │       └── griffon
│   │           └── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonController
│   ├── service-build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── org
│       │           └── example
│       │               └── SampleService.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── org
│                   └── example
│                       └── SampleServiceTest.java
├── settings.gradle
└── view
    ├── src
    │   ├── functional-test
    │   │   └── java
    │   │       └── org
    │   │           └── example
    │   │               └── SampleFunctionalTest.java
    │   ├── integration-test
    │   │   └── java
    │   │       └── org
    │   │           └── example
    │   │               └── SampleIntegrationTest.java
    │   ├── main
    │   │   ├── java
    │   │   │   └── org
    │   │   │       └── example
    │   │   │           ├── SampleController.java
    │   │   │           ├── SampleModel.java
    │   │   │           └── SampleView.java
    │   │   └── resources
    │   │       ├── META-INF
    │   │       │   └── griffon
    │   │       │       ├── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonModel
    │   │       │       ├── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonService
    │   │       │       └── griffon.core.artifact.GriffonView
    │   │       └── org
    │   │           └── example
    │   │               └── sample.fxml
    │   └── test
    │       └── java
    │           └── org
    │               └── example
    │                   └── SampleControllerTest.java
    └── view-build.gradle
```

I don't know if that structure is the one that makes more sense, but is the one I first thought of.

Regardless everything I tried I could not build this project and I am wondering if anyone could tell me if I made a mistake with the selection of the subprojects and what should be the content for the *build* files.

I created a zip file with the rearranged source [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7707848/simplified-subprojects.zip) keeping the original *build.gradle* file untouched, with a *settings.gradle* file that makes Gradle properly recognize the new structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by missing resource files in the `service` project. You'll find a similar problem in the `view` project. This is is because all resource files were moved to another location (the `resources` project). There was no problem before splitting the application into subprojects because all resources were at the right place.

You can fix the build by following these steps:

```
$ cd service
$ mkdir -p src/test/resources
$ touch src/test/resources/Config.properties
$ mkdir -p src/main/resources
$ mv ../resources/src/main/resources/messages.properties src/main/resources/

$ cd ../view
$ mkdir -p src/test/resources
$ touch src/test/resources/Config.properties
```

This should be enough to make the tests green again.

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo,
I've posted a new version of the multi-project build [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21656413/simplified-subprojects.zip). This version keeps common setup at the root level, leaving what's specific to each subproject on each subproject's build file.

Comment: Hi Andres, thank you so much for taking a look into this. The project runs fine but I have trouble testing it.
I added a missing testCompile dependency to service-build.gradle ("org.codehaus.griffon:griffon-core-test:${griffonVersion}") to allow the tests compile, but if I test the project it fails when the service test run.